# "Invite Fellow Experts" -- what does it do?

Tags: support

On the home page for the main site there's an ad labeled "Invite Fellow Experts" -- what does it do?

Meaning if the user gets the invite, do they get access to the private beta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they get an invitation to the private beta.

> Hello,
>
> $YOUR_NAME told us you're just the right kind of expert a Chess -
>   Stack Exchange Q&A site needs.
>
> This new Stack Exchange Q&A site is currently in private beta, but
>   since you've been recommended by a peer, we're giving you super secret
>   access to get in early and help shape the community.

Comment: Thanks, and 'super secret access' made me laugh... :-)